# How to retrieve a message based on its' index number?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, client, message

My question is about retrieving the message type after saving the message index in PlayerPrefs in Unity.

I'm using a message system in my client / server system, based on this [tutorial set](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amy3L3pGWH0&t=1465s)

For example message "CreateAccount":

The NetOP script hold the index

```
public static class NetOP
{
    public const int None = 0;
    public const int CreateAccount = 1;
    public const int LoginRequest = 2;
}
```

The NetMsg class manages the messages

```
public abstract class NetMsg
{
    public byte OP { set; get; } //OP = operation code, a single number to know what is this message

    public NetMsg()
    {
        OP = NetOP.None;
    } 
}
```

There's a class for this message:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Net_CreateAccount : NetMsg
{
    public Net_CreateAccount()
    {
        OP = NetOP.CreateAccount;
    }

    public string UserName { set; get; }
    public string Password { set; get; }
    public string Email { set; get; }
}
```

When the client receive the message, on Client.cs script:

```
 public void MessageReceived(NetMsg msg)
 {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("msg",msg.OP); //save the msg index in PlayerPrefs
    print(msg.OP); //check the message index is correct       
 }
```

So far so good, now the Client need to retrieve the received message since it got disconnected (by mistake), so on Client.cs

```
   ...case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
            isConnected = true;
            Debug.Log("We have connected to the server ");
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("msg") > 0) //we have a msg in PlayerPref
            {
                //ISSUE HERE:
                communicationManager.CheckMessageStatus(connectionId,PlayerPrefs.GetInt("msg"));
            }
            break;
            ....
```

the communicationManager.CheckMessageStatus(int connectionID, NetMsg msg) - takes an int, and a NetMsg (not the NetMsg.OP which is the index). 
I know how to find the index of a NetMsg, but I don't know how to trace the NetMsg back based on its index.

Is it possible (from the script snippets I've posted) to  trace the message based on the index? 
I'm still learning C# so please help.

Comment: You probably want to construct a new `NetMsg` and assign its OP with the value saved in PlayerPrefs.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to say: NetMsg msg = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("msg", _____) - in the line it says msg.OP, it's like, how do I go back? if to get the OP I go msg.OP, to go back I need only the Msg. like I need to construct a constractor that says: const NetMasg 1 = CreateAccount. if it were math I need to go from this: msg X OP, to this: msg / OP

Comment: `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` takes one parameter and returns a value. `int localVar = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("msg");`  Also, don't use PlayerPrefs to store gamestate (i.e. it is not a good location to serialize data to).

Comment: I have an issue with my server/client system. My client gets disconnected and reconnected unexpectedly, and the system doesn't know where to continue from. Maybe it's a new question, but I really need to understand how to deal with it. My guess is this is a known behavior in such systems and there's a way to handle it.

Comment: @Draco18s no longer trusts SE I don't know how to use the int localVar to find the NetMsg

Comment: Well', you're not storing a list of `NetMsg` objects anywhere. There's no where to *go* to fetch one by ID. And again, why are you using PlayerPrefs for this?

Comment: My current decision is to store a list, as you wrote above, and to create a json file storing player position in the game (like scene, or task) and the msg, so it can be restored on random disconnect, and this data will be cleaned once the game restart (not disconnected) and on the first launch of the game